# PHP [Array Keys] : Convert "0" Into "A", "1" Into "B"... (and so "89" will be "IJ") Function

Tags: php, function, array-key

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
$array = array
("this","is","me","and","I","am","an","array","hello","beautiful","world");
```

**How can I create a function that converts 0 into "A", 1 into "B"...?**  *Using `Foreach` or...?*

So that instead of

```
 Array
(
    [0] => this
    [1] => is
    [2] => me
    [3] => and
    [4] => I
    [5] => am
    [6] => an
    [7] => array
    [8] => hello
    [9] => beautiful
    [10] => world
)
```

I would get

```
 Array
(
    ['A'] => this
    ['B'] => is
    ['C'] => me
    ['D'] => and
    ['E'] => I
    ['F'] => am
    ['G'] => an
    ['H'] => array
    ['I'] => hello
    ['J'] => beautiful
    ['BA'] => world
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function digits_to_letters($input) {
    return strtr($input, "0123456789", "ABCDEFGHIJ");
}

$result = array_flip(array_map("digits_to_letters", array_flip($original)));
```

(Example run: http://ideone.com/TQNYj)

---

If you preferred a `foreach` over `array_flip`+`array_map`, you could use this instead:

```
$result = array();
foreach($original as $k => $v) {
    $result[strtr($k, "0123456789", "ABCDEFGHIJ")] = $v;
}
```